# Siebel On Demand with QTP

Tags: qtp

Can we automate Siebel CRM On Demand with QTP?

Comment: Yes - depends on which version of QTP you are using.

Comment: @diagonalbatman -- why don't you enter this as an answer?

Comment: @TheBlastOne simply because i didn't think it added enough value to be an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can Automate SIEBEL CRM with QTP.
For that first we need to Install Siebel Add-In, and then we are going to design the framework.
SIEBEL AddIn has more methods and keywords.